# split count between group members

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a SQL result that looks like this:

```
+-----------+------------+
| AGENTCODE |  DEAL_ID   |
+-----------+------------+
|    110434 | SO20001353 |
|    108415 | SO20001344 |
|    106188 | SO20001344 |
|    107689 | SO20001342 |
|    109150 | SO20001340 |
|    109150 | SO20001341 |
+-----------+------------+
```

If I group by agent code and count `deal_id` I get a number of deals per agent,
logically for me, if a deal has more then one agent it each should get 1/agents for that deal. Is this an option for SQL or do I need to write a program for this?

My desired result would look like this:

```
+-----------+-------+
| AGENTCODE | DELAS |
+-----------+-------+
|    110434 |     1 |
|    108415 |   0.5 |
|    106188 |   0.5 |
|    107689 |     1 |
|    109150 |     2 |
+-----------+-------+
```

Thank you.

Current code

```sql
SELECT d.AGENTCODE,
       SUM(c.DEAL_COUNT) AS DEALS
FROM (
         SELECT AGENTS.AGENTCODE,
                ORDERS.ORD
         FROM AGENTS,
              BRANCHES,
              CPROFTYPES,
              ORDERS,
              ORDSTATUS,
              ORDERITEMS,
              TRANSPAYMENT,
              TRANSORDER
         WHERE ORDERITEMS.EPI_AGENT = AGENTS.AGENT
           AND ORDERITEMS.PART = 25 /*5003*/
           AND ORDERS.ORD = ORDERITEMS.ORD
           AND ORDERS.BRANCH = BRANCHES.BRANCH
           AND ORDERS.ORDTYPE = CPROFTYPES.CPROFTYPE
           AND TRANSORDER.EPI_PAYDATE BETWEEN 16830720 AND 16917120
           AND ORDERS.ORDSTATUS = ORDSTATUS.ORDSTATUS
           AND ORDSTATUS.ORDSTATUSDES != 'canceled'
           AND TRANSPAYMENT.ORD = ORDERS.ORD
           AND TRANSPAYMENT.TRANS = TRANSORDER.TRANS
           AND TRANSORDER.EPI_CKPAY = 'Y'
           AND TRANSORDER.TRANS != 0
           AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 'X'
                          FROM TRANSPAYMENT TRP
                             , TRANSORDER TRS
                          WHERE TRP.ORD = ORDERS.ORD
                            AND TRP.TRANS = TRS.TRANS
                            AND TRS.EPI_PAYDATE
                              > 16917120
                            AND TRS.TRANS != 0)
           AND CPROFTYPES.TYPECODE IN ('21', '22', '26', '29')
     ) AS d
         CROSS APPLY (SELECT 1.00 / COUNT(*) AS DEAL_COUNT FROM ORDERS WHERE ORD = d.ORD) c
GROUP BY d.AGENTCODE
ORDER BY d.AGENTCODE;
```

Comment: You can use `Row_Number()`

Comment: I see lots of tables in the `FROM` clause and no `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
    AGENTCODE int,
    DEAL_ID varchar(10)
)
INSERT INTO Data
    (AGENTCODE, DEAL_ID)
VALUES
    (110434, 'SO20001353'),
    (108415, 'SO20001344'),
    (106188, 'SO20001344'),
    (107689, 'SO20001342'),
    (109150, 'SO20001340'),
    (109150, 'SO20001341')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT d.AGENTCODE, SUM(c.DEAL_COUNT) AS DEAL_COUNT
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY (SELECT 1.00 / COUNT(*) AS DEAL_COUNT FROM Data WHERE DEAL_ID = d.DEAL_ID) c
GROUP BY d.AGENTCODE
ORDER BY d.AGENTCODE
```

Result:

```
AGENTCODE  DEAL_COUNT
106188     0.5000000000000
107689     1.0000000000000
108415     0.5000000000000
109150     2.0000000000000
110434     1.0000000000000
```

Comment: I tried to implement your answer, but i get incorrect results, I add my full code to the question, I think i'm not counting properly (it's counting all deals)

Comment: I'm now getting  same results as a simple count, not splitting, updated code,
thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
  select AGENTCODE,   
     COUNT(AGENTCODE ) OVER (PARTITION  BY  DEAL_ID) * 1.00  / COUNT( DEAL_ID) OVER (PARTITION  BY   AGENTCODE) * 1.00  AS DELAS 
  FROM Data;
```

Demo :  https://rextester.com/ENK8799

Result :

```
    AGENTCODE   DEAL_ID
1   110434  SO20001353
2   108415  SO20001344
3   106188  SO20001344
4   107689  SO20001342
5   109150  SO20001340
6   109150  SO20001341

    AGENTCODE   DELAS
1   106188  2,000000000000000
2   107689  1,000000000000000
3   108415  2,000000000000000
4   109150  0,500000000000000
5   109150  0,500000000000000
6   110434  1,000000000000000
```

Comment: If you want to remove duplicate record, add group by on AGENTCODE and DELAS